# Recursive program in Scala doesn't run

Tags: list, scala, recursion

I am trying to write a program in Scala using recursion to see if two lists are disjoint. This is my first time writing a program in Scala.

```
object Main {
    def member(x:Int,lst:List[Int]):Boolean= {
        if (lst == Nil)
            return false
        else
            if (x != lst.head)
                return member(x, lst.tail)
            else
                return true
    }

    def disjoint(s1:List[Int], s2:List[Int]):Boolean= {
        if (s1 == Nil)
            return true
        else
            if (member(s1.head,s2))
                return false
            else
                return disjoint(s1.tail, s2)
    }
     def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val lst1 = 2 :: (6 :: (1 :: Nil))
        val lst2 = 1 :: (3 :: (5 :: (7 :: (9 :: (11 :: Nil)))))
        val lst3 = disjoint(lst1, lst2)
     }
}
```

It compiles but it doesn't run. All help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am getting lst3: Boolean = false

Comment: you can omit all the `return` words here, by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
def areDisjoint[T](s1: Seq[T], s2: Seq[T]): Boolean =
  (s1.toSet & s2.toSet).isEmpty

val lst1 = List(2, 6, 1)
val lst1a = List(2, 6)
val lst2 = List(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11)
println(areDisjoint(lst1, lst2))
println(areDisjoint(lst1a, lst2))
```

=>

```
false
true
```

The trick is to use the `&` operator on [Sets](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.Set) to do the work for you. `Set` uses a hash to efficiently test whether a given object is a member or not.

Comment: I want it to work on lisp style lists where lst.head is car and lst.tail is cdr.

Comment: It does. `Seq[T]` makes it work on any kind of sequence: `List`, `Array`, and lots more.

Comment: I tried it with  val lst1 =7 :: (6 :: (1 :: Nil)) and val lst2 = 1 :: (3 :: (5 :: (7 :: (9 :: (11 :: Nil))))) but it doesn't work. It still returns false.

Comment: Those lists are not disjoint. Each contains a `1`.

BTW, `List(7, 6, 1)` is the same as `7 :: (6 :: (1 :: Nil))`.

Comment: @OshaMan it should return false

Comment: Thank You. My dumb mistake. I forgot what it was supposed to do. I was porting over a function I had written in python to scala.

Comment: So your first version was correct, after all. :) Well, now you know a few Scala idioms, too. (BTW, the same trick works in Python, too.)

Comment: How do you convert a list to a set?

Comment: `lst.toSet`. `List` has a method called `.toSet`. Documentation (too terse for newbies, IMO, but at least you can see what all the class members are) is [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@toSet[B>:A]:scala.collection.immutable.Set[B]).

Comment: How do I store a tuple of form (2,(6,(8,(),()),(5,(),())),(4,(3,(),()),(10,(),())))

Comment: You can just say `val tup = (2,(6,(8,(),()),(5,(),())),(4,(3,(),()),(10,(),())))`. Type it into the REPL and see what happens. BTW, you might want to ask a new question if this is something new. That'll give you an opportunity to provide context, too.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use recursion just to see how to recurse down a list in Scala, here's how:

```
def isMember(x: Int, l: List[Int]): Boolean =
  l match {
    case Nil => false
    case head :: tail => x == head || isMember(x, tail)
  }

def areDisjoint(l1: List[Int], l2: List[Int]): Boolean =
  l1 match {
    case Nil => true
    case head :: tail => !isMember(head, l2) && areDisjoint(tail, l2)
  }
```

`match` does ["pattern-matching"](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/pattern-matching.html), which provides a syntactically easy way to extract the head and tail from a `List`. Note that this is really not good Scala code in practice, for three reasons:

1. It does linear searches and runs in O(n^2) time. The `Set` version runs much faster, at least on large lists.
2. `List` already has a built-in `.contains` method (see [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List)), so you really don't need to write `isMember`.
3. It's limited to working on `List[Int]`. The `Seq[T]` version works with any kind of sequence, containing items of any type.